# Why is JPS showing no process running?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am running a hadoop using the apache-hadoop binary and i have started dfs, yarn and mr deamon using the following commands:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

After this everything is working fine, viz, i could see the HDFS UI, resource amanger UI, Job History UI etc.

Here is the jps command output:

```
sh-3.2# jps
61601 Jps
sh-3.2#
```

But, when i am checking which processes are running using the jps command, it is showing no processes running, no name node, no datanode, no resource manager, no secondarynamenode. Even though, i could comfortably copy files from and to local to HDFS, make directory on HDFS etc.

My question is why the jps command is not showing the processes which are actually running? Do we need to invoke jps with some other argument to check the processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [jps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jps.html) documentation:

> The list of JVMs produced by the jps command can be limited by the permissions granted to the principal running the command. The command only lists the JVMs for which the principle has access rights as determined by operating system-specific access control mechanisms.

In practical terms, this typically means that `jps` only prints information for JVM processes owned by the same user running `jps`.  In a typical Hadoop cluster, the daemons are run under different users, e.g. user `hdfs` for the NameNode and user `yarn` for the ResourceManager.  If you have `sudo` access and run `jps` as one of these users, then you can see the processes.

Comment: my hadoop cluster was running using the KV user. However, i still tried sudo su and ran the jps, but no luck.

Comment: I have a case where the java processes are running under the same user I'm logged in as, and yet jps doesn't display them. I've also tried jps as root, and it's the same. I'm quite puzzled.

Comment: Problem was related to /tmp/hsperfdata* -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805376/jps-returns-no-output-even-when-java-processes-are-running