# Commands like jps, jstat, jstack, etc show "<pid> not found"

Tags: java, jvm, tomcat9, jvm-hotspot, jstat

I am running Tomcat 9 on an Ubuntu 20.04 OS using OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode).
When I try to gather diagnostics info using jstat, jstack, etc, I see *PID* not found. jps also cannot identify the Tomcat process id.

I have checked several posts like [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159564/jstack-and-jstat-stopped-working-with-upgrade-to-jdk6u23), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805376/jps-returns-no-output-even-when-java-processes-are-running), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file), [four](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/jvm-is-not-reachable-with-jstat-and-jstack-1031281491.html), etc, but none of the answers given in these helped me to solve my problem!

Even though I am passing the username with which the Tomcat process is running, jstat cannot find that process: `sudo -u tomcat jstat -gc 476174 5000`

In case it matters:

1. I can see that the Tomcat process is started with `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp`
   This folder is owned by root user but has full permissions(777) enabled.
2. When the Tomcat process is started, I can see a folder with name `systemd-private-e6d8b5dc224848f8a64a3e943ac2e9c4-tomcat9.service-UH5knj` (the last few chars after service- change every time the process is restarted) getting created with owner as root (probably because I start tomcat service using `sudo service tomcat9 start`) and this folder has permission of `rwx------`.

Any hints on how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Shobhana

Comment: Seems like Tomcat process is started in a different mount namespace. JDK 8 utilities do not support namespaces (while JDK 11 does). Try [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach): `jattach <pid> threaddump`

Comment: @apangin thank you for your response. How can I check whether the Tomcat process is started in a different mount namespace?

Comment: `stat /proc/PID/ns/mnt`; `stat /proc/PID/root`

Comment: Thanks @apangin; in deed Tomcat is started in a different mount namespace. I am running on an ubuntu instance; can I still use jattach? Installation instructions in [this](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) link talk about FreeBSD, AlpineLinux and ArchLinkx only

Comment: Also, is there any other way to run the JDK 8 utilities by specifying them to use the same tmp space as that of Tomcat process or by changing any permissions?

Comment: Replied to your questions in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66127051/3448419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20 the Tomcat 9 service runs in a private tmp space by default and because of that the java tools cannot find its pid.

This private tmp setting is defined in `/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service` as `PrivateTmp`. It is set to "yes" by default. You could edit that file directly but the recommended way to make changes is to create an override file using this command:

```
sudo systemctl edit tomcat9
```

Add the following content to the file and save:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=no
ReadWritePaths=/tmp/
```

It will create this file with your content: `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/override.conf`

Then you need to reload the systemd daemon and restart Tomcat:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart tomcat9
```

You should now be able to call the java tools using sudo directly, e.g. `sudo jstat...`. For some reason it does not work when I try to run it as the tomcat user with `sudo -u tomcat jstat...`

Comment: Thank you David! I will try this as well

Answer (score 1):

All these tools (jstack, jmap, jstat...) rely on the [communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670135/how-do-jps-jinfo-jstat-jmap-and-jstack-get-information-about-local-java-proce) with the target JVM through `/tmp` directory.

Apparently Tomcat runs in a different mount namespace, so that its `/tmp` directory is not the same as `/tmp` of the current shell. To verify this, run

```
readlink /proc/$$/ns/mnt
readlink /proc/<java_pid>/ns/mnt
```

and check if `inode` numbers are different.

Unforunately, JDK 8 tools do not support Linux namespaces. You may try [`nsenter`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) to launch these tools under Tomcat's namespace.

Or simply use JDK 11 (or newer) tools, which support containers (and thus namespaces) out of the box. They also work with applications running under JDK 8, e.g. jstack from JDK 11 can dump threads of a JDK 8 process.

Alternatively, there is a small [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) utility which can be used in place of jstack, jmap, and jcmd. It also supports containers out of the box. It does not require installation - there is just a single [standalone binary](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases).

Comment: thank you for your time and response. I will check out both nsenter and jattach